# Django - Is it okay to have a model with only one field?

Tags: sql, django, django-models

In 5th grade when we learned how to outline a research paper, our teacher taught us that you should never have a single bullet point. I feel like I am breaking this rule, and there might be a better way.

I have model, `Movie`, which has fields like `title` and `year`. I want to also include `genre`. However, movies can fall into more than one genre. So I feel like I need to have a many-to-many relationship. But I don't really want to make `Genre` it's own model class, because there would only be one field, `Genre.genre`. It seems wrong to me. I know I could have genre be a CharField and separate genres with some sort of a separator sentinel, ie `action|adventure|comedy`. But is that the best way to do it?

I am planning to run raw SQL queries against this database, so simplicity is of high value right now.

Comment: Try https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multiselectfield/ or https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-select-multiple-field/ . With this,you don't need to separate the choices by comma as genre choice strings may contain commas themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such general rule of quality regarding models with a single attribute. As movies can have more than one genre and genres obviously can belong to more than one movie, a `ManyToMany` relationship might be your best shot here.

One alternative would be to have a `genres` `TextField` in your model, and simply save all the genres as a comma separated list. Among many obvious problems of this approach are the fact that you wouldn't be able to efficiently query movies by genre and there would be no guarantee that the same genre wouldn't be written differently in two different movie instances.

If you are using PostgreSQL, another option is to define `genres` as an  [ArrayList](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield) of `CharField`s. Define a constant with every possible genre and pass it to your `CharField`'s [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#choices).

```
COMEDY = 'COMEDY'
ADVENTURE = 'ADVENTURE'
ACTION = 'ACTION'
# ...

GENRE_CHOICES = (
    (COMEDY, 'Comedy'),
    (ADVENTURE, 'Adventure'),
    (ACTION, 'Action'),
    # ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no such rule. It makes sense for the `genre` to be a separate model. So querying all genre and accessing the movies fall in that genre would be more straight forward.

If you are still feeling weird, put a `created_time` and `created_user` field in the `Genre` model. You will find it useful later.